# Pandas DataFrame data types change unexpectedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a script that solves sudoku puzzles. I use a `pandas.DataFrame` for the sudoku itself and the numbers are integers.

When I check which numbers are possible in a box and multiple numbers fit the requirements, I put the numbers as a `list` within the box. Because of this, I need the `dtype` of all of the columns of the `DataFrame` to be `object`.

The problem is that at some point in my code, the `dtype` changes to `float64` unexpectedly.

Here, I make a copy of the `DataFrame` and I change the `list`s to `NaN`s to check the requirements:

```py
sudoku_copy = sudoku

for column in range(sudoku_copy.shape[1]):
        sudoku_copy[column] = sudoku_copy[column].apply(
            lambda x: x if str(x).isnumeric() else np.nan
        )
```

I have to do this because later I use `isin()` to check whether a number is already in a column, row or subgrid, and this raises an error if there are `list`s in there.

I checked the `dtype` of `sudoku` right before and right after that statement and the problem is there. The `dtype` before is `object`, but after, it's `float64`. However, the statement only changes `sudoku_copy`, not `sudoku`, so I don't see why `sudoku` changes at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw such issue in practice. This is because you insert NaNs into your DataFrame, ie.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([range(3), range(3)]) 
df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
0    int64
1    int64
2    int64
dtype: object
```

Then:

```
df.iloc[0,0] = np.nan 
df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
0    float64
1      int64
2      int64
dtype: object
```

If you want to preserve the original, then you should use the `copy()` method to create a separate copy:

```
sudoku_copy = sudoku.copy()
```

That is because the `copy()` method creates a new object and the assignment from the original code creates a reference to the existing object.

Comment: Yes, but in my case, I make a copy of the DataFrame and insert `NaN`s in the copy, but the *original* DataFrame changes

Comment: That worked, thanks! But why does simply putting `sudoku_copy = sudoku` link them together? If I say `a = 1`, then `b = a`, and `a += 1`, `a` will be 2 and `b` will be 1 (so they're not linked). Why is this different with DataFrames?

Comment: Your code only made a reference while `copy()` creates a new object.